# How to set the attributes of checkboxes in a single column tableview

Tags: cocoa, checkbox, datasource, tableview

I'm reviewing a sample program where a series of checkboxes were presumably created in a tableview by dragging the Checkbox cell into a single column using IB.  In the sample the AppDelegate was the datasource with implementations of numberOfRowsInTableView:, setObjectValue:, and objectValueForTableColumn:.

In objectValueForTableColumn: the state of the checkboxes is being set with '0' or '1' in an array being returned.

What I'm unclear about is:

1)  How to set the attributes of the checkbox in each row?  For example how does one set the checkbox title?  In the sample each checkbox of each row is titled "checkbox".  I want each to have a unique title for each checkbox in each row.

2)  How to set other checkbox button attributes such as enabled/disabled etc. ?

3)  How are the checkboxes getting created?  I'm assuming that they are somehow created after numberOfRowsInTableView: is called, when objects in the NIB are being instantiated.  How does one best access these objects to do things like changing of attributes?  Apple's TableView document for all its wordiness seems to lack any examples that would clarify.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an example.

Follow the Steps to accomplish:

1. Drag and Drop a table View.
2. Drag and Drop a table Cell View (NSTableCellView) inside the Table View Cell. Now, Your table view is view based.
3. Set The Identifier for table Cell View (NSTableCellView) as "CheckBoxCell" -> NSTableCellView of the first Column and the other column's table cell view as "TextBoxCell".
4. Delete the image view present inside the NSTableCellView.
5. Drag and Drop a Check Box(Not NSButtonCell, it should be NSButton).
6. Drag and Drop array controller and place an outlet "myArrayController"

> ```
> @interface ExAppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate,NSTableViewDelegate>
>
> @property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
>
>
> @property (strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;
>
> @property (strong) IBOutlet NSTableView *myTableView;
>
> @property (strong) IBOutlet NSArrayController *myArrayController;
>
> @end
> ```

```
@implementation ExAppDelegate
@synthesize myArray;
@synthesize myTableView;

- (void)applicationWillFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [self.myTableView setDelegate:self];
    if(self.myArray == nil)
    {
        self.myArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (NSUInteger i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *test = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
            [test setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",i] forKey:@"Name"];
            NSUInteger marks = i + 10;
            [test setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",marks] forKey:@"Marks"];
            [self.myArray addObject:test];
        }
    }
   [self.myArrayController rearrangeObjects];
}



- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
    NSTableCellView *checkBoxCell = nil;

    if(tableView == self.myTableView)
    {
        //Get the Column Number
        NSUInteger tableCol = [tableView.tableColumns indexOfObject:tableColumn];
        if(tableCol == 0)
        {           
           checkBoxCell = (NSTableCellView *)[tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"CheckBoxCell" owner:tableColumn];
            NSArray *myViews = [checkBoxCell subviews];
            NSButton *checkBoxButton = [myViews objectAtIndex:0];

            NSDictionary *valueDictionary = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:row];
            NSString *titleValue = [valueDictionary valueForKey:@"Name"];
            [checkBoxButton setTitle:titleValue];

            NSUInteger mod = row % 2;
            if(mod == 0)
            {
                [checkBoxButton setState:NSOnState];
            }
            else
            {
                [checkBoxButton setState:NSOffState];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            checkBoxCell = (NSTableCellView *)[tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"TextBoxCell" owner:tableColumn];

        }
    }   

    return checkBoxCell;
}

@end
```

=============================================

*Bindings(Ignoring Data Source)
myArrayController - > bind to - > ExAppDelegate  - > Content Array - > model key Path -> self.myArray
tableView - > bind to -> Table Content - > Content Array - > arrayController -> arranged Objects.
DO NOT SET ANY MODEL KEY PATH FOR TABLE VIEW BINDINGS*

=============================================

1. I have set a Outlet as mytableView to NSTableView
2. Assuming Two Columns in a Table View
3. Assuming one column should be set with a Check Box Cell and the other with a Text Field Cell

*You want to set the Unique title to the check box cell along with marking as checked or not.
(FYI : I alternatively marking checked and unchecked, Like 1st row will be checked and the second will be unchecked and so on...)

1. I'm considering an Array Containing a Dictionary with 2 Keys -- > 1st Key (Name) 2nd Key(Marks)
2. Then Later Implement the method "- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row"

   I Hope this will be help in fixing the issue. :)

Comment: I appreciate the code example, but unfortunately I need a cell based tableview in order to run on versions of OS X prior to 10.7.

Answer (score 2):

As per the comment "I appreciate the code example, but unfortunately I need a cell based tableview in order to run on versions of OS X prior to 10.7."

In that case, You can comment the method

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
```

*And you can use the delegate method(willDisplayCell) for that replacement. Make sure you remove the method and make the table view as cell based. Drag and drop check box(NSButtonCell). Implement the same.
Rest all remains the same.*

```
/* Delegate Method For the same example explained in the above answer */
    - (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
    {
        NSUInteger tableCol = [tableView.tableColumns indexOfObject:tableColumn];
        if(tableCol == 0)
        {
            NSDictionary *valueDictionary = [self.myArray objectAtIndex:row];
            NSString *titleValue = [valueDictionary valueForKey:@"Name"];
            [cell setTitle:titleValue];

            NSUInteger mod = row % 2;
            if(mod == 0)
            {
                [cell setState:NSOnState];
            }
            else
            {
                [cell setState:NSOffState];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            [cell setTitle:@"Column 2"];        
        }
    }
```

This should be what you are expecting : )

For your information: The Table View Object should be in following way:

[image]

And the Table View Bindings should be in the below way

[image]

And the Array Controller Binding should be in the below way:

[image]

Let me if you are still facing the issue.

Comment: I'm assuming steps 4&5 no longer apply?Delete the image view present inside the NSTableCellView.
Drag and Drop a Check Box(Not NSButtonCell, it should be NSButton).
Drag and Drop array controller and place an outlet "myArrayController"

Comment: Per step 6 "
Drag and Drop array controller and place an outlet "myArrayController" " Can you elaborate on this step?

Comment: yes, you are right. Instead of NSButton it should NSButtonCell(Drag and Drop NSButtonCell(check box) to NSTableView). It depends on you, I have used myArrayController to call "rearrangeObjects". You can ignore "myArrayController" if you are using NSTableViewDataSource. And i have binded the tableview -> tableContent -> myArrayController. The "myArrayController" is binded to self.myArray.

Comment: For your easy understanding i have edited the answer please go through it.

Comment: Okay, you are using bindings versus the datasource way, correct?  I'm trying what you are suggesting but the thing is that I only want 1 column.  I'd like to be able to have headings in the column (by hiding the checkbox and only showing its label. And then the checkbox label identifies it not text in a second column like you show.  Sorry, I'm very new to Cocoa.  If you consult I'd be interested in possibly hiring you to clarify some things for me via Skype and a remote session

Comment: It isn't working nothing is showing in the tableview.  I setup the binding connections as you indicated

Comment: Nothing is showing in the table view indicates that the binding to the table view is not proper. Could you please check the table view binding? The Array controller should call "rearrangeObjects" and the table view should be binded to table Content - > Content Array - > Array Controller